# How to tell someone to call you by a certain name, but they're free to use whatever suffix they please?

Tags: names, culture, suffixes, spoken-language

Say my name is Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious, but since that name is obviously nuts, they can feel free to call me by my nickname "スーパ". But I don't mean for them to just refer to me as "スーパ" with no suffix (呼び捨て). They should call me "スーパ+さん/くん/ちゃん" as they see fit. Is there any particular way to indicate this, or is it already implied?

In particular, what I think I might say is "僕はスーパカラ何々何々です。どうぞスーパと読んでください。"

However, I'm not exactly sure what the implication might be here. Is it implied "call me スーパ (with whatever suffix you want)" (which is what I desire)? Or is it implied "Call me スーパ (呼び捨てで)" (which is not what I want)? And if it's the latter, how should I phrase things to imply the former?

Comment: I am not an expert but, it is okay to say "好きに呼んでください。でも呼び捨ては無しで。" I suppose. In general, depending on the situation but, some of Japanese people are familiar with western habit of calling first name without suffix, calling Mike as "マイク" but not "マイクくん" or "マイクさん" if there is no huge age difference. So, if you don't want them to call you without suffix, saying "呼び捨てはちょっと" explicitly would be important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No Japanese native will interpret （名前）と呼んでください as an instruction to leave honorifics off of your name. They will absolutely add honorifics to your name if you're conversing in Japanese, until there is some other reason for them to change how they call you. It's totally normal to introduce just your name and then for people to apply the honorific of their choice. You don't need to tell them to from the start.